# How to use alias name in find query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How can we use an alias name in `find` method of mongodb as we do in mySQL like:

`select user_id as id from users`

Please provide some help, thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please refer to Aggregation pipeline : [Project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

Following query should do the job :

```
db.users.aggregate([{$project:{id:"$user_id"}}])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use mongodb aggregate method with pipeline stages to get the desired result:
[list of stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/)

eg. :

```
db.[collection].aggregate(pipeline)
```

Pipeline contains different stages:

pipeline = [{match, projection, ...}]

There are other parts also in stages, please refer to the link mentioned above.

In your case i can write below query:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$match:{"_id":"<some_value>"}},{$project:{id:"$user_id", default_key:"default_value", "excluded_key": 0, "included_key": 1}}])
```

**$match:{"_id":""}}** -> This is matching query , its output will be executed in next stage. eg. $projection in our case.

**id:"$user_id"** -> in this case we are giving id as alias name to user_id key in mongo-db collection.

**default_key:"default_value"** -> in this case default_key field will be added in the response with default value mentioned in place of "default_value".

**"excluded_key": 0** -> in this case excluded_key will be removed from the response.

**"included_key": 1** -> in this case included_key will be part of the response.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: @Raghav Salotra I m checking very similar, but my element is inside the object.

Comment: @Raghav Salotra I m having very similar issue, but my element is inside the object.{"Data" : {
        "data" : [ 
            {
                "count" : "0",
                "videopath" : []
            }]
        }
} Can somebody please help me i tried .aggregate([{$project:{"bitlensObj.Data.data[0].count":"$count"}}])

Comment: @AyyappaA did you try below query:

{"Data" : { "data" : [ { "count" : "0", "videopath" : [] }] } } Can somebody please help me i tried .aggregate([{$project:{"Data.data.count":"$count"}}]
I think you don't need to provide index of the nested record.

Comment: @Raghavsalotra Not working i did my trails."Data" : {
        "data" : {}
    } i got this

Comment: @AyyappaA can you send me the some records with in above schema and final output you want. i will try and post the answer ?